# PDF equation images not exporting to HTML from Keynote

Tags: html, latex, keynote

I have used Keynote for several years to create slides for Math courses I teach.   One very nice feature of Keynote (and, I imagine, of PowerPoint as well) is that graphics can be animated, adding just a bit more excitement to that lecture on vector addition (:-)).  I used to export these animated slides to HTML from Keynote, and was very impressed with how well they displayed on iPads, iPhones, desktops, etc.

Recently, I upgraded to Keynote 6 (from 9 - go figure), and was disappointed to see that while I could still export animations to the web, none of the mathematics equations I had created in Latex (via LatexIt, or some other means) were exporting properly.  In place of [] for matrices, I get cute apple symbols (is this Apple's idea of a joke?).  And the fonts no longer render properly.  This was all working fine in Keynote 9.

Has anyone  else discovered this "bug" and found a workaround?  I can export my slides to PDF, but the web HTML version was much nicer.